# corresponding method in tridion core service for GetListPublishItems

Tags: tridion

Is there any method in tridion core services which can give me a list of components published on a specific target. Using search filter data i can get the component which are published it will not give me result for a specifi target.

Regards,
Rajendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `PublishTransactionsFilterData` and then either `GetSystemWideListXml` or `GetSystemWideList` methods:

```
var filter = new PublishTransactionsFilterData();
filter.PublicationTarget = new LinkToPublicationTargetData{ IdRef = "tcm:x-xx-xxx"};
client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
client.GetSystemWideList(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the list of items. Is there any way to set itemtype property for the same as well. though i can filter the xml for components.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Please clarify, or ask as another question. BTW, there are already plenty of lists Questions, you can check some of them

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called resolving. You can use ICoreService2011.ResolveItems (or something similar depending on which core service/client you are using).